# Need help solving an acute-triangle to find the distance to the outside of my object

Tags: unity, 2d, trigonometry

I recently asked a question here: [How would I check the range against the entirety of an enemy object, and not just it's transform.position?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99262/how-would-i-check-the-range-against-the-entirety-of-an-enemy-object-and-not-jus)

That was accurately answered, and works perfectly fine. However, now I need to find the distance from the center of a non-rectangular object to it's edge as illustrated here: [image]

I have the length of `Side A`, and the angle between `Side A` and `Side C`, as well as the angle between `Side A` and `Side B`. I am missing a couple things:

- The length of `Side B`
- The length of `Side C`

My end goal is to get the length of `side C`. It is important to note that my math skills are barely comparable to first year college algebra. I heavily rely on the methods provided within Unity to calculate dot products, angles, and distances without much understanding of their inner workings.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Is your object always an equilateral hexagon? Because if so, you know angle AB, as well (60°). Given that, you know angle BC = `(180 - (60 + angleAC))`. And once you know 1 side and its opposite angle, you can use the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find the others. You can also use the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) in many convenient cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your insight made me realize I can get the AB angle even if it's not equilateral because I know the direction of both vectors that make up that corner. I will read into the law of sines and consines

Comment: You should convert the comment to an answer and mark this question as solved.

Comment: How do I mark his question as the answer? Or do I write it myself?

Comment: His comment* I meant